# How to add modal window parameters for this code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

JavaScript code:

```
function openBlockEditor(block, nick) {
var blockInfo = $.ajax({
    url: "in/GameElement/BlockEditor.php",
    type: "GET",    
    data: 'block=' + block + '&nick=' + nick,
    dataType: "html"
});

blockInfo.done(function(msg) {
    $("#dialog-modal").html(msg).dialog();
    $('.ui-dialog-title').html("Block editor")
});

blockInfo.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    alert( "Please report this: " + textStatus );
}); }
```

I am using default jquery css and js files. Please show me the proper way to add some modal dialog parameters on this code? I am learning ajax. This code working 100% but i need some examples how to set dialog window animation and size parameters. Thanks.

Comment: There is no standard for these kinds of "dialogs". All I can see is that the element has id `dialog-modal`. You should try things like `$("#dialog-modal").css({width: 400})` etc.

Comment: can you show me where to put this code? that would be helpful, because im new at javascript and ajax programming

Comment: Judging by your code, you'd put it before the `$("#dialog-modal").html(msg).dialog();` line.

Comment: thank you very much! and i wanna ask how to add animations too?

Comment: [google it!](http://google.com/search?q=jquery+animations)

Comment: i dont know how to add it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of executing `.dialog()` without any options

just pass some, you´ll find a lot in the documentation http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/
some animation and your title could for example be.

```
$("#dialog-modal").html(msg).dialog({
  title:"Block editor",
  show: {
    effect: "blind",
    duration: 1000
  },
  hide: {
    effect: "explode",
    duration: 1000
  }
});
```

the options are just passed as an object, to understand it, this is exactly the same

```
var options =  {
  title:"Block editor",
  show: {
    effect: "blind",
    duration: 1000
  },
  hide: {
    effect: "explode",
    duration: 1000
  }
}

...  .modal(options)
```

to make it functional, for your case maybe sth like :

```
function openModal(selector,content,title){
    $(selector).dialog({
          open:function(){
            $(selector).html(content);
          },
          title:title,
          show: {
            effect: "blind",
            duration: 1000
          },
          hide: {
            effect: "explode",
            duration: 1000
          }
    });
}
```

you simply open dialogues like :

```
blockInfo.done(function(msg) {
    openModal("#dialog-modal",msg,"block content");
});
```

so you are variable to choose content title and selector, you could pass everything declared in the documentation

have fun!